# How do I output someone's Steam 64 ID when they click on a button?

Tags: web, steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to create a program in which, when you login with Steam and then there's a button, which when clicked the following happens:

If you are not logged in, it takes you to the login.

If you are logged in, it writes the user's Steam64ID onto a txt file somewhere in the site folder.

I currently read the steam web API documentation but i don't know how i can output someone's steam64ID with a button click. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1430511) API in order to login the user, this returns their Steam64ID. You can then store this (perhaps as a cookie) and output it on the click of the button (assuming you use PHP for the cookies, you could use Ajax for this)